# Error while using 'google-api-dotnet-client' to access FusionTables

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to work with FusionTables API. But I am getting this error:

> Method 'get_Error' in type 'Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v1.Data.Table'
>   from assembly 'Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v1, Version=1.2.4737.25287,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Can some one please help me with this error? Here is my code:

```
 // Create the service.
 if (fTableService == null)
 {
     // Register the authenticator.
     var auth = CreateAuthenticator();
     fTableService = new FusiontablesService(auth);
     if (fTableService != null)
     {                   
         name = fTableService.Table.List().Fetch().Items[0].Name;
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mix between assemblies versions (of the generated API and of the google client library itself).

Try to download the latest version of FusionTables API from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Fusion_Tables_API. 
The bundle contains all the dlls you need to reference.

Good luck

Comment: ok, I will try that sometime this weekend and get back to you. Thanks for the reply. I almost gave up.